# Placing list items correctly in a nested dictionary

Tags: python

I have a list of text blocks like this:

```
blocks = [
    "created may 27th", 
    "Introduction Foo Bar Bar", 
    "Lorem te Ipsum", 
    "Method Participants Foo Foo Bar Procedure Baz"
]
```

And the following dictionary:

```
structure = {
    "text": [],
    "Introduction" : {
        "text": []
    },
    "Method": {
        "Participants" : {
            "text": []
        },
        "Procedure": {
            "text": []
        }
    }
}
```

I want to combine the two so that the text blocks end up in their correct location based on the order of presence and possible header strings at their start to create the following structure:

```
structure = {
    "text": ["created may 27th"]
    "Introduction" : {
        "text": ["Foo Bar Bar", "Lorem te Ipsum"]
    }
    "Method": {
        "Participants" {
            "text": ["Foo Foo Bar"]
        },
        "Procedure": {
            "text": ["Baz"]
        }
}
```

This should work for a list of any length, as well as for a dictionary with any depth.

My intuition told me to loop through the text block and then to recursively find its location by checking if `block.startswith(header)`, if so splitting the header and repeating with the right partition of the text block, and otherwise appending to currently selected 'text' value. The biggest challenge for me is having 2 for-loops traversing through the text blocks and dictionary items, while keeping track of the location in the dictionary and being able to move towards the next item when it means going back up into the tree.

This is what I have tried:

```py
def add_block(block, current_section, header_index=0):
    header = list(current_section.keys())[header_index]
    if not block.strip().startswith(header):
        current_section['text'].append(block)
    elif block.startswith(header):
        block = block.partition(header)[-1]
        add_block(block, current_section[header], header_index+1)    

for block in blocks:
    add_block(block, structure)
```

Comment: Is the list "blocks" always 4 entries long, or could the Introduction span several list entries? (rather than just the two)?

Comment: @Amiga500 depth and length of both dictionary keys and list items is not constrained.

Comment: do the /n tags matter, or you can work w/o them

Comment: at first get all the keys from all the depths of the dictionary, then manipulate the blocks as per..join all the items in the block and do a string manipulation...this should work

Comment: @sadbro Unfortunately that does not account for duplicate keys appearing in different levels of the dictionary.

Comment: @tijmenvanetten then use a set upon the list of keys to get a unique list of keys

Answer (score 0):

Given length of keys/items unconstrained, it may be best to break the list "blocks" into sublists before trying to assign into structure.

```
subLists = {'text':[], 'intro':[], 'method':[]}

posits = ["text", "intro", "method"]
positSwitches = ['Introduction', 'Method', "###"]  #Last entry is just an impossible string so we don't go out of range.
iPosits = 0
for line in blocks:
    if left(line[:len(positSwitches[iPosits)] == positSwitches[iPosits]:
        #We are at first line of a new entry, i.e. moving from text to intro
        iPosits = iPosits + 1
     
    subLists[posits[iPosits]].append(line)
```

The above should give us a dictionary that breaks out the list "blocks" into 3 lists, for each item. From that, you could assign to separate functions for populating structure. Untested unfortunately and I have to run - but hopefully a basis to work from!